# How to get data from prop.location.state in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom, browser-history

I try to send data through history push like that.
[image]

And then I try to get the value of id that I send.
[image]

The problem is when the first time rendering of component, I got the value of undefined.
And then when I click the previous button on browser then I got the value.
Why could be happened ???

Answer (score 1):

Default state is missing, so use componentDidMount life cycle and inside componentDidMount call default state.

Answer (score 0):

send params in the url.

Define the route

```js
<Route path="/bookingform/:id" component={BookingForm} />
```

and then in the component you can get the id by
props.match.params.id

Answer (score 0):

It would help if I could see how you're writing your  component.

to make this code work, this should help.

```
<Route exact path="" render= {routeProps => (<theComponent {...routeProps} />)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a `state` to `push` method as the second parameter, `push(url, state)` not `push({ pathname, state})` .Example below

```
// Home.jsx
const Home = (props) => {
  // the second value in push method is the state
  handClick = () => props.history.push('/login', { comingFromHome: true })
  return <HomeBigOrSmallComponent onClick={handleClick} />
}
```

then, access the state

```
// Login.jsx
const Login = (props) => {
  // now let's log our state
  useEffect(() => console.log(props.history.location.state.comingFromHome), [])

  return <LoginBigOrSmallComponent onClick={handleClick} />
}
```

[History objects](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history) typically have the following properties and methods:

- length - (number) The number of entries in the history stack
- action - (string) The current action (PUSH, REPLACE, or POP)
- location - (object) The current location. May have the following properties:

  - pathname - (string) The path of the URL
  - search - (string) The URL query string
  - hash - (string) The URL hash fragment
  - state - (object) location-specific state that was provided to e.g. push(path, 
    state) when this location was pushed onto the stack. Only available in 
    browser and memory history.
- push(path, [state]) - (function) Pushes a new entry onto the history stack
- replace(path, [state]) - (function) Replaces the current entry on the history 
  stack
- go(n) - (function) Moves the pointer in the history stack by n entries
- goBack() - (function) Equivalent to go(-1)
- goForward() - (function) Equivalent to go(1)
- block(prompt) - (function) Prevents navigation ([see the history docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history#blocking-transitions))